# Is the following map linear over the space of density matrices?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, mathematical-physics, linear-algebra, density-operator

I have a map $\mathcal{N}$ from the space of two-qubit subnormalised density matrices $\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H}_2 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2)$ to itself (positive operators with trace between 0 and 1). Notice that it is not necessarily a physical one (e.g. it may be nonlinear, that's perfectly fine). I know $\mathcal{N}$ is

1. linear for all product states $\rho_A \otimes \rho_B$. By this I mean $\mathcal{N} \left( \sum_{ijkl} c_{ik}d_{jl} |i\rangle \langle k| \otimes |j \rangle \langle l | \right)= \sum_{ijkl} c_{ik}d_{jl}  \mathcal{N} \left( |i\rangle \langle k| \otimes |j \rangle \langle l |  \right)$ for every $\rho_A = \sum_{ik}c_{ik}|i\rangle \langle k|, \rho_B = \sum_{jl}d_{jl}|j \rangle \langle l|  \in \mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H}_2)$
2. continuous on the whole space of two-qubit density matrices $\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H}_2 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2)$.

Does it automatically follow that $\mathcal{N}$ has to be linear over all $\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H}_2 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2)$?

Comment: What does "linear for all product states" mean? Can you write a formula?

Comment: Do you require the map to be trace-preserving (i.e. $\mathcal S$ are positive operators with trace one)? Generally, I think being more specific (formulas!) in the question would be rather helpful.

Comment: You're right, I could have stated the question more carefully. Hope the edit helps clarify what I mean.

Comment: We do not require the map to be trace preserving

Comment: But is $|i\rangle\langle k| \otimes |j\rangle\langle l|$ a density matrix, or in particular positive?...

Comment: yes, tensor products of two qubit density operators.

Comment: but $|i\rangle\langle k|$ is not a density operator for a single qubit.

Comment: yes, the density operators are $\sum_{ik} c_{ik} |i\rangle \langle k|$ and $\sum_{jl} d_{jl} |j \rangle \langle l |$

Comment: Well, but then $\mathcal N$cannot be defined on $|i\rangle\langle k|\otimes |j\rangle\langle l|$, no? What I mean is that you write " map [...] from the space of two-qubit subnormalised density matrices [...]to itself". But if I am not completely mistaken, then $|i\rangle\langle k| \otimes |j\rangle\langle l|$ is *not* from the domain of the map.

Comment: You're right. The issue does not figure in the special case I have at hand, although the generalisation I made here is flawed. Maybe I'll restate the problem more carefully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

First, choose a continuous map $f(\rho)$ into the reals, such that

1. $f(\rho)$ is zero on all separable states (the convex hull of product states)
2. $f(\rho)>0$ for all other states.
3. $f(\rho)\le 1$.

Such a map exists -- e.g., it could be the (trace norm) distance to the set of separable states, or some nice entanglement measure (for two qubits: negativity, entanglement of formation, ... ), suitably normalized.

Then, construct
$$\mathcal N(\rho) = f(\rho) \sigma_1 + (1-f(\rho))\sigma_2$$
for any two states $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$.

This map will be linear on the separable states (in fact, constant, namely $\sigma_1$), and thus on all product states. On the other hand, it will not be linear in general. In particular, any separable state can also be decomposed as a convex combination which contains entangled states, $\rho=\sum p_i \rho_i$ with some $\rho$ entangled, and $\mathcal N$ will not be linear over such a decomposition, as $\mathcal N(\rho)=0$, while $\mathcal N(\rho_i)\ne0$ for some $i$, and $p_i>0$.

Comment: I started writing this answer before the OP clarified in their comments. If the map needs not be trace preserving $\mathcal N(\rho) = f(\rho)\sigma_1$ will do.

Comment: ... or $\mathcal N(\rho) = f(\rho)\rho$, for that matter.